# How can I interact with my webserver from Lua?

Tags: mysql, lua, webserver

I have a XAMPP web server running as well as MySQL running. I have a website that interacts with my database, but I was wondering how I would go about interacting with my database with HTTP requests, in my case through Lua. Any examples or tutorials you point me to would be great, thanks.

Comment: http://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/